# The drop-down menu should be closed, except for the main page, how should I do?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, web-frontend

```
 <CSidebar
     show={show}
     onShowChange={(responsive) => dispatch(changeState(responsive))}
 >
```

The drop down menu should be closed, except for the main page. This is how the drop down menu is defined in my project. Should I make changes using Route or is there another easy way around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with

```
 <CSidebar
     show={location.pathname === '/'}
     onShowChange={(responsive) => dispatch(changeState(responsive))}
 >
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the default value of show to false except for when defined otherwise.

in side bar:

```
 export default function CSidebar({show:false}) {
     return (
         <div>
             //if show === true then show
         </div>
     )
 }
```

Comment: I'm new to react, trying to learn. That's what I want to do anyway, but I'm getting errors. For example, how should I maintain control? Can you help me?

Comment: SyntaxError: C:\Users\alara\OneDrive\Masaüstü\aday-degerlendirme-fe-main\src\containers\TheSidebar.js: 'import' and 'export' may only appear at the top level.  ----the error i got